# Github with eclipse error

Tags: eclipse, github

i created a new repository in github and doing initial master push to the github from local. i'm getting error **master rejected non fast forward**

Please help me out how to push the data to github

[image]

Comment: its a new repo in git i created. anyhow my repo is empty

Comment: i need to do a initial commit from my local repo

Comment: It's not empty, I can see a license file in the repository. Either pull first or create a new _empty_ repository.